# Wordpress + apache2 + mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache

I have a VPS server which hosted an wordpress site. Why the website is running, there have too many processes spawn. It causes to leak memory and mysql is cracked? Can you guys help me? Thank you much.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a pretty general question. It could be because of a wordpress plugin (most of the times). It could also be an issue with the wordpress theme that you are using. Least but not last you should check your apache access log for that site and the error log as well. There could be some sort of brute force attempts that just spawn proccesses. The default location on centos for apache logs is /var/log/httpd if not configured otherwise.

Comment: I check logs, but it just said no memory allocate. I will check the plugin and templates. ty for your answer.

Comment: Then your vps is using all the available memory. Try a service httpd restart to stop and then restart apache. Then check the plugins and the logs